# Azure - Disk Snapshots accumulating and costing. Where do they come from?

Tags: azure, storage, vhd

I have a storage container in Azure (Premium, LRS, General Purpose v1)
which has about 7 disks , 1023 GiB each.

Upon reviewing the subscription costs breakdown, **half of the cost of this account is from snapshots** that are sitting on the underlying VHDs in the vhd container.

The snapshots are all created on random days 2-3 days apart, around 5pm.

Questions

1. Where are they coming from / how are they being generated?
2. How can I automate clean-up?

Thoughts

1. Are they coming from backup / Recovery Services Vault process?
2. Powershell get-snapshots | delete-snapshots ?

Comment: Are these managed disks, or the older standard disks in a storage account?

Comment: These are not managed disks. They are VHDs in a storage account which are attached as data disks to a VM which is a database server.

Answer (score 0):

Azure backup will use snapshots to backup the VM's, but these should then be stored in the backup vault, they should be cleaned up from the storage account.

You need to use the [remove-azurermsnapshot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/remove-azurermsnapshot?view=azurermps-6.4.0) command to delete them.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused by what you're saying - Azure backup uses snapshots that are automatically stored in the recovery services vault? If so then why do I need to do a clean-up task on my storage account?

Comment: I'm saying that if those snapshots were created by Azure Backup they should have been cleaned up, so either there is an issue with Azure Backup (have you checked your logs) doing the cleanup or they came from elsewhere. If they are not coming from Azure Backup then usually this would mean they have either been created manually or by some sort of script or automation.